# How can I show the image in a labelframe which is inserted through askopenfilename?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginner in python and having a tough time. Unable to show the image in the labelframe. (PS- The syntax of the function OpenFile is correct. Here I am unable to indent it properly :P)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("python gui")
root.geometry("1200x600")

def OpenFile():
    name=askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/Batman/Documents/Programming/tkinter/",
                       filetypes =(("JPEG FILE", "*.jpg"),("PNG FilES","*.png"),("bitmap","*.bmp")),
                       title = "Choose a file."
                       )
    print (name)

    try:
        with open(name,'r') as UseFile:
            print(UseFile.read())
    except:
        print("No file exists")

buttone=Button(embedtab,text="select image",command=OpenFile)
buttone.grid(row=1,column=0)

labelframe3=tk.LabelFrame(embedtab, text="originsal image", padx=100,pady=100)
labelframe3.grid(column=0,row=0)
ttk.Label(labelframe3, text="original image will display here").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious how you intend the `OpenFile()` function to work. Why not let Pillow open the image, see my example.

In my example I'm creating the label to hold the image first. I configutre it to display an image only when I have an image to display.

I set the labelframe to a specific size and use `grid_propagate()` to keep it from changing size when I show the image in the contained label.

The image appears in the top left corner in the labelframe. You can change this by calculating appropriate padding from image size etc.

Was this what you were after?

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("python gui")
root.geometry("500x400")

def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir=".",
                           filetypes =(("JPEG FILE", "*.jpg"),
                                       ("PNG FilES","*.png"),
                                       ("bitmap","*.bmp")),
                           title = "Choose a file.")
    print (name)

    try:
        pillow_img = Image.open(name)   # Open image with Pillow
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pillow_img) # Convert to PhotoImage
        original_frame.config(image=tk_img) # Put in label
        original_frame.image = tk_img       # Save reference to image
    except:
        print("Can't read file")

buttone = Button(root, text="select image", command=OpenFile)
buttone.grid(row=1,column=0)

labelframe3 = LabelFrame(root, text="original image", width=200, height=200)
labelframe3.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20)
labelframe3.grid_propagate(False)

original_frame = ttk.Label(labelframe3)
original_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Thank you so much